# Is there an algorithm to sort or filter a database table by distance to a vector, other than the naive one?

Tags: database, search

Say I have a large database table whose entries are vectors. I wish to do a search and sort by distance to a vector. The naive way consists in every time computing the distance between my vector and each of the ones from the database, then sorting by that distance.

Is there any other known algorithm for doing this, perhaps involving some type of indexing in advance?

Alternatively, are there known implementations of such algorithms, for say SQL or Elasticsearch?

Comment: A vector is a magnitude and a direction (*without* location information). How do you calculate the "distance" between two vectors?

Comment: @Bohemian In this context I'm referring to the norm of their difference.